# How can i iterate on time series row and get the Time stamps at specific values?

Tags: python, pandas

Here the values are increasing from 0 to 1, staying 1.0 for a short period of time and again start decreasing till 0. 
I have this huge Dataframe where values are fluctuating in this pattern everyday.

My question is, how can i find at which time stamp or time the value got increases  from 0 to some value, and say 1.0 (it can be greater than 1 sometimes but always lesser than 1.5) is the peak value. 
Then for how long it was 1.0 and how long it took to decrease again till 0. I need to find the average of this behaviour.

The output should be the Timestamps, at which Timestamp val just became greater than 0, from which timestamp till when the val was at it's peak and at which time stamp it became again 0. The total time from 0 till again 0.
Val are the behaviour of a motor engine.

````
import numpy as np

# taking some random values
rng = pd.date_range('2018-01-15', '2018-01-17', freq ='1H', closed ='left')

Val = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.2,0.4,0.7,0.8,1,1,1,1,0.6,0.5,0.2,0,0,0,
       0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.1,0.3,0.6,0.9,1,1,1,1,0.6,0.5,0.2,0,0,0,0,0,0]

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng, 'Val': Val})
df
    Date                    Val
0   2018-01-15 00:00:00     0.0
1   2018-01-15 01:00:00     0.0
2   2018-01-15 02:00:00     0.0
3   2018-01-15 03:00:00     0.0
4   2018-01-15 04:00:00     0.0
5   2018-01-15 05:00:00     0.0
6   2018-01-15 06:00:00     0.0
7   2018-01-15 07:00:00     0.2
8   2018-01-15 08:00:00     0.4
9   2018-01-15 09:00:00     0.7
10  2018-01-15 10:00:00     0.8
11  2018-01-15 11:00:00     1.0
12  2018-01-15 12:00:00     1.0
13  2018-01-15 13:00:00     1.0
14  2018-01-15 14:00:00     1.0
15  2018-01-15 15:00:00     0.6
16  2018-01-15 16:00:00     0.5
17  2018-01-15 17:00:00     0.2
18  2018-01-15 18:00:00     0.0
19  2018-01-15 19:00:00     0.0
20  2018-01-15 20:00:00     0.0
21  2018-01-15 21:00:00     0.0
22  2018-01-15 22:00:00     0.0
23  2018-01-15 23:00:00     0.0
24  2018-01-16 00:00:00     0.0
25  2018-01-16 01:00:00     0.0
26  2018-01-16 02:00:00     0.0
27  2018-01-16 03:00:00     0.0
28  2018-01-16 04:00:00     0.0
29  2018-01-16 05:00:00     0.0
30  2018-01-16 06:00:00     0.0
31  2018-01-16 07:00:00     0.1
32  2018-01-16 08:00:00     0.3
33  2018-01-16 09:00:00     0.6
34  2018-01-16 10:00:00     0.9
35  2018-01-16 11:00:00     1.0
36  2018-01-16 12:00:00     1.0
37  2018-01-16 13:00:00     1.0
38  2018-01-16 14:00:00     1.0
39  2018-01-16 15:00:00     0.6
40  2018-01-16 16:00:00     0.5
41  2018-01-16 17:00:00     0.2
42  2018-01-16 18:00:00     0.0
43  2018-01-16 19:00:00     0.0
44  2018-01-16 20:00:00     0.0
45  2018-01-16 21:00:00     0.0
46  2018-01-16 22:00:00     0.0
47  2018-01-16 23:00:00     0.0




 ### output should look like this 
```result = pd.DataFrame({ 'motor_s': '2018-01-15 07:00:00' , 's_val': 0.2 ,
                       'motor_max_s': '2018-01-15 11:00:00' , 'max_s_val' : 1.0,
                     'motor_max_e' :'2018-01-15 15:00:00', 'max_e_val' : 0.6,
                      'motor_e' :'2018-01-15 18:00:00', 'e_val' :0 }, index=[0])```


motor_s : start time when the val became greater than 0
s_val : sarting val
motor_max_s : timestamp when the motor running at full speed 
max_s_val : maximum start value 
motor_max_e : time stamp when the val became lesser than max_s_val which is 1.0
max_e_val : maximum end value
motor_e : timestamp when motor stopped running
e_val : that end value which is always be zero
````

Comment: This is an interesting question. Could you to show what the output you are looking for is? For example given the input shown above what should the output be, a list of dates? A dictionary? and what exactly should the values in those objects be?

Comment: could you show the expected resutl for this data?

Comment: @johnchase The output can be in data frame again. Showing  at 2018-01-15 01:20:00 the value was 0.5 (greater than 0), then it took 20 minutes to reach peak value. For 40 mins it was peak value 1.0 and started decreasing, reached 0 again in 40 mins. 
The Ouput can be in Dataframe or list giving only the time stamps.

Comment: Thanks @ArpitGothwal. This information should really go in the question itself to make it self contained. The formatted expected output would be very useful

Answer (score 0):

I used [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/index.html), I assume that the input has been read as a string.

```py
import datetime
import numpy as np


date_vals_str = '''2018-01-15 00:00:00  0.0
2018-01-15 01:00:00  0.0
2018-01-15 01:20:00  0.5
2018-01-15 01:40:00  0.8
2018-01-15 02:00:00  1.0
2018-01-15 02:20:00  1.0
2018-01-15 02:40:00  1.0
2018-01-15 03:20:00  0.6
2018-01-15 03:40:00  0.4
2018-01-15 04:00:00  0.0'''

val_was_zero = False
prev_val = -1.0
prev2_val = -1.0
prev_date = None
vals = []
dates = []

for l in date_vals_str.splitlines():
    print(l)
    date_time, val = l.split('  ')
    val = float(val)
    date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    dates.append(date_time_obj)
    vals.append(val)


vals_arr = np.array(vals)

epsilon = 0.001
zero_idx = np.where(vals_arr<epsilon)
diff = np.diff(vals_arr)
starts = np.intersect1d(zero_idx, np.where(diff>epsilon))

for i in starts:
    print('Value just became greater than 0 at {}'.format(dates[i]))

max = np.r_[False, vals_arr[1:] > vals_arr[:-1]] & np.r_[vals_arr[:-1] >= vals_arr[1:], True]
max_idx = np.where(max==True)


for i in np.nditer(max_idx):
    print(vals[i])
    print('Peak val: ({}) was at {}'.format(vals[i], dates[i]))

# print(max_idx)
# print(max)
# print(starts)
# print(diff)
# print(zero_idx)
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is somewhat incomplete, here is an approach which extracts the required indicators for a full DataFrame with multiple cycles:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# get some more cycles (df_0 is the example data)
df = pd.concat([df_0 for _ in range(5)])
df['Date'] = pd.date_range('2018-01-15  00:00:00', 
                           '2018-01-15  16:20:00', freq='20min')


# identify the pattern features and add to dataframe
features = {'ramp_start': (df.Val > 0) & (df.Val.shift(1) == 0),
            'max_start': (df.Val == 1) & (df.Val.shift(1) < 1),
            'max_end': (df.Val == 1) & (df.Val.shift(-1) < 1),
            'zero_start': (df.Val == 0) & (df.Val.shift(1) > 0),
            'zero_stop': (df.Val == 0) & (df.Val.shift(-1) > 0)}
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(features)], axis=1)

# add a cycle group index
df['cycle_id'] = df.ramp_start.cumsum()

# group by cycle id and get relevant time stamps
# Note: could also group by day, if cycles are strictly by day
def get_indicators(x):
    data = {name: x.Date.loc[x[name]].iloc[0] if x[name].sum() else 0
            for name in features}
    return pd.Series(data)    

df_ind = df.groupby('cycle_id').apply(get_indicators)

# delete incomplete cycles
df_ind = df_ind.loc[~(df_ind==0).any(axis=1)]

# use the data to calculate derived indicators
df_ind['total_time_zero'] = df_ind['zero_stop'] - df_ind['zero_start']

Out[199]: 
                   ramp_start            max_start              max_end  \
cycle_id                                                                  
1         2018-01-15 00:40:00  2018-01-15 01:20:00  2018-01-15 02:00:00   
2         2018-01-15 04:00:00  2018-01-15 04:40:00  2018-01-15 05:20:00   
3         2018-01-15 07:20:00  2018-01-15 08:00:00  2018-01-15 08:40:00   
4         2018-01-15 10:40:00  2018-01-15 11:20:00  2018-01-15 12:00:00   

                   zero_start            zero_stop total_time_zero  
cycle_id                                                            
1         2018-01-15 03:00:00  2018-01-15 03:40:00        00:40:00  
2         2018-01-15 06:20:00  2018-01-15 07:00:00        00:40:00  
3         2018-01-15 09:40:00  2018-01-15 10:20:00        00:40:00  
4         2018-01-15 13:00:00  2018-01-15 13:40:00        00:40:00
```

Comment: thanks for your answer it helped a lot. Can i also get the value at that particular time stamp. I have updated the question to understand the output.

Comment: to get the values you can modify my function `get_indicators` accordingly. e.g. by adding `data['val_ramp_start'] = x.Val.loc[x['ramp_start']].iloc[0] if x['ramp_start'].sum() else 0`

Comment: thanks for your reply. Will the function works if i modified it to give me the index values? As i have set my index as dates. and just want the value of that index + val.

Comment: If you look at the output of zero_start and and zeo_stop the values are not right. As ramp_start at 00:40:00 and max_end was 02:00:00 so the total time of running should be 00:40:00 - 02:00:00 that is 01:20:00. but total_time_zero is showing 00:40:00

Comment: `total_time_zero` is calculated from `df_ind['zero_stop'] - df_ind['zero_start']`, so 03:40:00 - 03:00:00, which is 00:40:00, by all standards. This is just an example of calculating derived indicators for the cycle. Of course you can calculate `max_end - ramp_start`, if that's what you need, or any other time difference you require.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59006612/how-to-get-first-occurring-minimum-value-and-its-index-in-a-time-series
Can you look in to this. if it's possible